# Auto-Completion (VS 2017)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I cant resolve several issues which concern comfortable typing in VS2017 and must to say after hours that I've spent - Microsoft VS sucks.

1. How change hotkey TAB to Enter? When i start entering function name for example `myFuncisHuge` i don't wanna type all thing,i entering just first two letters `my` and if highlighted name beneath correct - simply press my lovely Enter button.But no,only way to do so - press button "Down" and then "Enter".Or "TAB" which i don't like.
2. No auto-parentheses for functions when i use autocomplete .Again,start entering name of function,use auto-complete with TAB(disgusting), it complete name of my func but i have add parentheses manually and after them semicolon...

I've came here after hours of surfing internet with this questions,i really dont understand why guys in Microsoft do such bad, why in QT or Embarcadero everything fine for default, when in most popular IDE i have to spent extra-hours for resolving basic things like that.

Comment: I feel your pain. Every update of Visual Studio seems to make this stuff worse.

Comment: I have the latest VS2017 Pro: 1) In C# at least, I can autocomplete with both Enter and Tab, in C++ only Tab works. There seems to be no Setting, but I feel like there was one. 2) Paren-Completion works for me. (Tab-complete function, type open-paren, close paren appears, youre in a editor macro, you can type in arguments and with Tab it'll jump after the closing paren.

Comment: so there is no answer for autocomplete parentheses...okay